# Launching certbot-auto fails on OLD_VENV_PATH

Tags: solaris, certbot

Im trying to install certbot on SunOS 5.11. certbot-auto should, as I understand it, create a virtualenv and take care of all the dependencies, but launching it fails with this error message:

```
./certbot-auto: OLD_VENV_PATH=~/.local/share/letsencrypt: is not an identifier
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like cerbot conflates POSIX `sh` with `bash`.  I'd file a bug report.

Comment: Hm, I tried running it with bash and that worked, but I can't imagine that something so basic was simply overlooked.

Comment: [All too common](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+is+not+sh), especially for inexperienced Linux-only developers who are unaware that many Linux distros actually run `sh` as `bash` and enable a lot of non-standard functionality in `sh`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5900